# C# toUpper for language without Uppercase

Tags: c#

When using [`String.toUpper()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper(v=vs.110).aspx) are there any additional precautions which must be taken when attempting to "format" a language which does not contain uppercase characters such as Arabic?

```
string arabic = "مرحبا بالعالم";
string upper= arabic.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sidebar: Never call `.ToUpper()` or `.ToLower()` when localization matters because these methods do not accept an explicit `IFormatProvider` that makes your intent (about localization) clear. You should prefer `CultureInfo.TextInfo.ToUpperCase` instead.

But to answer your question: case-conversions do not affect characters not subject to casing, they are kept as-is. This also happens in `en-US` and other Latin-alphabet languages because characters like digits `0, 1, 2` etc don't have cases either - so your Arabic characters will be preserved as-is.

Note how the non-alphabetical and already-uppercase characters are ignored:

```
"abcDEF1234!@#" -> "ABCDEF1234!@#"
```

Another thing to be aware of is that some languages have characters that don't have a one-to-one mapping between lowercase and uppercase forms, namely the Turkish I, which is written up here: https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/ (and it's why FxCop yells at you if you ever use `ToLower` instead of `ToUpper`, and why you should use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` or `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` and never `str1.ToLower() == str2.ToLower()` for case-insensitive string comparison.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. The link about Turkey I had no idea about so that was especially valuable!