# How to check if Arabic/Persian character is lowercase?

Tags: c#, .net, string, char

The concept of lowercase/uppercase is slightly different in English and some RTL languages like Arabic/persian , I want to check whether a persian/Arabic character is a big or small letter.

I tried char.IsLower method but it does not work for RTL languages.

Please see the following code snippet:

```
             string mainString = "مرحبا";
             char[] arr = mainString.ToCharArray();
             bool Lcase= char.IsLower(arr[3]);
```

I want to know if the fourth letter (from the right) is small or large?
But `Lcase` always gets false while it must be true.

I can not even get a small letter in these languages, because `arr[3].ToString()` gets uppercase character ("ب") always.

[image: please look at this image]

Comment: Please see the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273363/c-sharp-toupper-for-language-without-uppercase

Comment: I thought that Arabic had neither uppercase or lowercase characters?  In which case, these characters are effectively neither

Comment: @Flavio Francisco , it is not the same as my Question.

Comment: Fair point @Martin, but just because it is Arabic/Persian does not mean that it will never contain A-Z. What if there's a URL in there?

Comment: @Martin , you are wrong, please look at above image.

Comment: NOTE:The concept of lowercase/uppercase is slightly different in English and some RTL languages like Arabic/persian , but these languages have uppercase or lowercase characters.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti The question is: _How to check if Arabic/Persian character is lowercase?_ What has this to do with A-Z characters?

Comment: @MitraM There are no uppercase or lowercase characters in Arabic.  The character can change depending on it's position (i.e. start\end\middle of word) but it's not _uppercase_.  Instead, each character has 4 possible configurations

Comment: So basically this sounds more like an Arabic language question rather than a programming one :)

Comment: @Martin  , So please tell me How can we check that configurations for a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reshape your string first, reshaping means convert your text characters into its glyph, for eg:

> ﺴ ﻼ ﻡ ﻋ ﻠ ﻴ ﻜ ﻢ

Then create a mapping for letters and compare them to understand what char is it. There are some libraries such as [iTextPDF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) that have an `ArabicLigaturizer` class that lets you Reshape your Arabic/Persian strings.

To create mapping you can get help from these libraries :

1. [python-arabic-reshaper](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper/blob/master/arabic_reshaper/letters.py)
2. [js-arabic-reshpaer](https://github.com/mapmeld/js-arabic-reshaper/blob/master/index.js)
3. [Reshape Arabic letters for Designers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsarabic/2011/03/23/reshape-arabic-letters-for-designers/)

I even used a code for .net code for reshaping for one of my free tools here at [github](https://github.com/al1b/KTOP/blob/master/src/ArabicShaping/ArabicLigaturizer.cs).

Comment: Although I think this method has impact on performance for the long strings, but I will try it. Thanks

Comment: One way or another you need to determine the shape of any letter, you can check the code and logic of any libraries I shared

Comment: OK, Im using C#+WPF , So I will try the last link that you placed and if it works, I'll let you know.

Comment: I think your answer is correct (+1 Vote) , but I made a simpler solution for that , please see my answer , Do you think my solution will work always?

Answer (score 0):

Try this which should reverse LTR to RTL:

```
string mainString = "مرحبا";
char[] arr = mainString.Reverse().ToArray();
bool Lcase= char.IsLower(arr[3]);
```

That said, as @Martin pointed out in a comment, Arabic (and neither the Persian alphabet) has no capital letters, so the value of Lcase will always be `false` if mainString contains only Arabic/Persian. This code above will still work in case you want to use RTL and check for the existence of capital letters, perhaps in text that contains text in the Western alphabet, like the name of some company or product, or even a URL.

Comment: these languages have uppercase or lowercase characters too,but the concept of lowercase/uppercase is slightly different.

Comment: @MitraM Java uses Unicode (as probably does your OS, window manager, fonts, etc). You have to take the same approach to Arabic as Unicode.org, maybe [TR #53](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr53/). (Sorry if the reference doesn't address the issue but Unicode.org is the place.)

Answer (score 0):

In Arabic, there is nothing called upper or lower case it's only one case, I think IsLower method internally uses a regular expression, something like matching it to [A-Z] regex so it's normal to have it always false

Comment: Yes, but just because it is Arabic/Persian does not mean that it will never contain A-Z. What if there's a URL in there?

Comment: these languages have uppercase or lowercase characters too,but the concept of lowercase/uppercase is slightly different.

Comment: I'm a native Arabic speaker, I'm 100% sure that no uppercase in Arabic

Comment: So, How you name differences between the two characters in the image above?

Comment: in Arabic, the letter takes different shape based  on its location inside the word and completely different shape when it's just a letter not inside word 
as for example: 
ب is the letter shape when it's not inside word 
بـ is the shape of the same letter if it the first letter in the word 
ــبـ is the same letter it in the middle of a word 
ــب is the same letter at the end of the word  
a bit complicated and cannot be mapped to the concept of upper and lower case in English

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if it is possible. Even if I force it to be either upper or lower case I have the same ASCII code.

```
    TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("ar-DZ",false).TextInfo;

    string mainString = "مرحبا";
    char[] arr = mainString.ToCharArray();

    Console.WriteLine((int)myTI.ToLower(arr[3]));

    Console.WriteLine(char.IsLower(myTI.ToLower(arr[3])));

    Console.WriteLine((int)myTI.ToUpper(arr[3]));

    Console.WriteLine(char.IsLower(myTI.ToUpper(arr[3])));

    string word = "word";
    arr = word.ToCharArray();           
    Console.WriteLine((int)arr[3]);     

    Console.WriteLine(char.IsLower(arr[3]));

    word = "WORD";
    arr = word.ToCharArray();                  
    Console.WriteLine((int)arr[3]); 

    Console.WriteLine(char.IsLower(arr[3]));
```

**Expected result**

1576

False

1576

False

100

True

68

False

Comment: What happens if you change the first line to:

````string arabic = "مرحبا بالعالم https://stackoverflow.com/a/56540736/9945524".ToLower();````

Comment: I want to check a character not whole the string.

Answer (score 0):

Hooray!!!

I myself invented! a simple solution to that. :)

my solution :

If the next letter does not exist or it is empty/space, the letter is big, otherwise it is a small/middle character.

It seems to work.

**UPDATE :**
Unfortunately this solution works only for Persian and does not work for all cases of Arabic language. So I accepted Ali Bahrami's answer.

Comment: It's not that simple. How about vovels? Whitspaces, Any non-arabic chars. For eg: نَ. In your logic ن is not the middle noon.

Comment: @Ali Bahrami , you are right it does not work for vovels. Thanks again.